# Access image present in a cell of googlesheet using python?

Tags: python, image, google-sheets

I've surfed internet many times but unable to find the solution of this problem.
Say, I have an image in a googlesheet cell, Now I want to read that image using python. 
As for now I can successfully read the data using access token from googlesheet but when I insert image in googlesheet and then try to read googlesheet it shows me nothing.

**Now I just want that when I read the image present in a cell of googlesheet will return me a binary of that image when I run the code in console.**

[image: That's how Image looks like in my googlesheet.]

Any help will be appreciated.

**Please Help**

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the possibility of gathering the image from the cell is not possible since Google Sheets doesn't have the capacity to return the blob of an image, only a reference to the image.

A possibility to retrieve the image is by inserting it using `=IMAGE()` and afterwards retrieve it by using a `GET` request, something similar to this:

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/[SPREADSHEET_ID]?includeGridData=true&key=[YOUR_API_KEY];
```

What you can do instead is to file a feature request on Issue Tracker by accessing this link [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191608&template=823917).

**Reference**

- [Sheets API v4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest);
- [IMAGE Sheets Formula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333?hl=en).